# Is it sure that there is always room to improve ourselves?

Tags: epistemology, meaning-of-life

There is always something that is stuck in my mind. I am afraid that one day... I mean what if one day, we know everything and did everything to improve ourselves and there is no more room for improvement? Has anyone thought anything about this before? I know that many people think it is impossible for us to know everything because we don't have the time, but I personally think this reason is not persuasive enough. Can someone please help?

This is troubling me because the purpose of my life is to keep on learning and improving myself.

Comment: Einstein thought about such things:"*"Imagination is more important than knowledge. For knowledge is limited, whereas imagination embraces the entire world, stimulating progress, giving birth to evolution.*" See also Rees's reflections in [Is There a Limit to Scientific Understanding?](https://www.theatlantic.com/science/archive/2017/12/limits-of-science/547649)

Comment: When you say "improve ourselves" and "know everything" do you mean for humanity as a whole? Because only that could possibly even approach making sense. But then you loop back around to your own life. So are you afraid that you might wind up knowing "everything" during your own lifetime?

Comment: When the need to imagine improvement goes, then the need to evaluate oneself goes too.

Comment: It's just going to depend on how you define improvement, for yourself. Look closely at what you mean by it.

Answer (score 3):

This is part of why people like Leibniz deduce that evil is necessary.  If the world were perfectible in this way, humans would finish the work of our species and then just be terminally bored.

But any force for good can always be turned to evil, and the things that make humans effective, such as competition and idealism are also easily turned into motives to destroy the work of others.

And Nietzsche points out that there is no risk of our becoming perfectly good and casting out all those motivated by evil.  We will always change our mind as to what is good before we get there.  Some part of humanity that is threatened by the disappearance of some evil will create a positive use for exactly that evil, because good and evil are subjective to a certain degree, and constantly reverse themselves.

So it is certain there will never be a shortage of evil, or too little evil to keep us busy working to limit it.

Answer (score 1):

This made me think of Spinoza, who might suggest that emotional states are “fluctuations”, a mobile *dynamism* capturing the relations of movement and rest between the parts of the body.

In other words you can always do *something* to become a little more cheerful, to augment your Potential by improving the “harmony” of your internal composition (relations of movement and rest within and between the “elements” of your organism.)

On the other hand, melancholy and other sad passions are a kind of breakdown or dis-accord in these internal movements or modes of infra-relations.

Sort of like how there is a minimal temperature, where a body is at total rest, melancholy has a limit; whereas cheerfulness, as a measure of harmony or accord within your dynamic composition, can always be increased through integrating your “speeds” ever more harmoniously. There’s always one more thing you can do which will improve the way you compose with the world, which will enhance the tone of your fluctuations.

Comment: More generally for Spinoza, self-improvement has no limit; and the augmentation of the intellect is effectively  equivalent to the Good in itself

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether this answer can satisfy you.

> This is troubling me because the purpose of my life is to keep on
>   learning and improving myself.

You didn't mention what is meant by the term-- 'improving myself'.  Different people have different aims according to their philosophy.  But those who could understand the potentialities of human have clearly mentioned about it.  The inquiry of human will not stop until he realizes himself clearly.  Then only one can understand clearly what that term means.

If one could realize himself he would explain that term in a different way.  I don't wish to mention it...please 'listen' to Vivekananda.

Swami Vivekanada says:

```
The ultimate goal of all mankind, the aim and end of all religions, is but one—re-union with God, or, what amounts to the same, with the divinity which is every man's true nature. But while the aim is one, the method of attaining may vary with the different temperaments of men.
```

http://www.swamivivekanandaquotes.org/2014/05/goal-of-mankind-swami-vivekananda.html

http://greenmesg.org/swami_vivekananda_sayings_quotes/life-goal_of_life.php

> I mean what if one day, we know everything and did everything to
>   improve ourselves and there is no more room for improvement?

If there is a term--'Vedanta' (the limit of knowledge) and many great men have used it, your doubt is true.

You can verify whether the term 'Paramahamsa' refers to any kind of improvement.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paramahamsa